# Game freezing when i create a body Box2D Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm implementing a Worms game using libGDX and Box2D and I'm  having a problem I didn't have until recently. When a player shoots, it creates a bullet body and applies a force to it. I have a step system to see what the player should be doing( move, select weapon, select angle and charge force). The methods involved with shooting in player are :

```
public void nextStep(){
    if ( turnStep == 0){
        startingPosition = player.getPosition().x;
    }
    turnStep++;
    if(turnStep > 5){
        turnStep = 0;
        chargeBar.dispose();
        movementBar.dispose();
        arrow.dispose();
    }
    if(turnStep == 1)
        movementBar = new MovementBar(getX(),getY(),world);
    if(turnStep == 3)
        arrow = new Arrow(getX() + tex.getWidth() /2, getY() + tex.getHeight() / 2,  world);
    if(turnStep == 4)
        chargeBar = new ChargeBar(getX(),getY(),world);
    if(turnStep == 5){
        shooting = true;
    }
}

public void shoot(){
    actualWeapon.shoot( arrow.getTip(), chargeBar.getCharge() , arrow.getAngle());
    shooting = false;
}
```

In my main game class, I have an update method where I do the world step and update other things, and I perform the shooting here

```
    world.step( 1/60f, 6, 2);
    if (playerWhoseTurnItIs.isShooting()){
        playerWhoseTurnItIs.shoot();
    }
```

Which ends up calling :

```
public void shoot(Vector2 pos, float force, float angle){
    isFlaggedForDeletion = false;
    body = BodyCreators.createBox( pos.x * PPM, pos.y * PPM, projectileTex.getWidth(), projectileTex.getHeight(), false, false, world, (short) BIT_PROJECTILE, (short) (BIT_PLAYER | BIT_WALL), (short) 0 , this);
    Vector2 f = new Vector2( force * MathUtils.cos(angle * MathUtils.degreesToRadians), force * MathUtils.sin(angle * MathUtils.degreesToRadians) );
    body.applyForceToCenter( f , true);
}
```

Everything used to work fine, and I didn't touch any of this while working, but now every couple of turns the bullet just appears and then freezes there, on the tip of the arrow, freezing my whole game.

Also, when I started having this problem I implemented the check after the world step, it just used to shoot when i called nextStep() and the turn was five, but since applying the check didn't actually solve the problem (I thought it was like when destroying bodies you can only do it after the step) I might revert the change.

If you need more information please ask, thank you